# Compiling Flash for Mac and PC

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, exe

Having only ever developed Flash for web I'm unfamiliar with methods of compiling a single executable file for both Mac and PC.

What I have at the moment is a whole mess of files and folders comprising .fla, .swf, .as classes, gallery images and videos and need to supply my client with a single 'solid' file to hand over to the end client.

The end product doesn't need to be both Mac and PC compatible as I can supply them with two versions, but a cross-platform version would be ideal.

Should I be using a third party to compile in this way or should I be looking to re-distribute my job via Flash Builder (I've never used this before) or is it possible to achieve all this in Flash itself?

**BONUS ROUND!**
Finally, just in case it's a possibility, is there a chance that this might also run on an iPad?!

Thanks very much for reading and I eagerly await some wisdom! 
Kev

*I'm using a Mac (Intel) and Adobe CS5.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of this could depend on what your client requirements are, but...

1. In Flash Pro you can create a projector, which I think is an exe.
2. Use [AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/articles/blackberry_playbook_battery.html); and give your client an .AIR file.  The end users will need the AIR Runtime installed for the program to run.
3. Create a [desktop native installer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html) with AIR.  I think this will still have a dependency to the AIR runtime being installed.
4. Use AIR 3.0 and [Captive Runtime](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html) features to provide your client with a DMG or EXE.  Flash Pro does not offer this as a feature yet; but it is expected for the next version.  Flash Builder just released an update which supports Captive Runtime.
5. Use a third party tool, such a [Zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/) to turn your SWCs into executable files.

And yes, you can generate a [native app for the iPad](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air_for_ios.html) [or iPhone] using the same tools.  But it seems unlikely that you'll want to because such an app will probably have different performance requirements and different UI Requirements.

Comment: You can also make projectors just using the [standalone player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) (File > Create projector...), which will be either `.exe`s or `.app`s depending on the OS, though you have less control over application features like window title/size/etc.

Comment: Hi @www.flextrasc.com, thank you first of all for your quick answer and my apologies for not responding sooner, the project was shelved and my attention away from Flash temporarily!

I've had a look at Zinc and, while it looks like just what a I need, I'm reluctant to pay £200 for a piece fo software that I may not need to use again, for this reason I've been looking at publishing and AIR application from Flash.  

The installation process isn't ideal but it will suffice, as long as my application is compiled into a single file my client will be happy. 

Many thanks
Kev

Comment: @blahdiblah, unless I misunderstand your answer I don't think that publishing to .app or .exe will solve my problem as the 'parent' file will still depend upon linking to external .swf and .xml files.  Is there a way to compile into a single file straight from Flash that I don't know about?  

Many thanks
Kev

Comment: @KevinNugent I wasn't sure which of the pieces you mentioned were  compile-time requirements vs. runtime requirements.  The former shouldn't be a problem.  For the latter you can probably just put them into the `Contents/Resources` folder in the `.app` bundle and use relative references on the Mac side, but I don't have a similar answer for Windows-land.

Comment: Thanks @blahdiblah, it's still a little foggy but I'll give it another go over the weekend. Just to clarify, do you think I'll be able to achieve this using just Flash Pro or will I need Flash Builder, Air or a third party application to make this happen?